# Retreive tags from attached post for media on page

Tags: attachments, get-posts, images, tags

I am working on a custom template file that pulls all images in my Media Library with a specific tag. I was able to get this working with some help from the community, it also shows the title of the post that the image is associated with. I need to pull the tags for post the image is attached to as a class name on a container.
This is my code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_parent' => null,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'logo'
            )
        )
    );

$images = get_posts( $args );
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        // Get the parent post ID
        $parent_id = $image->post_parent;
        // Get the parent post Title
        $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );
        // Get the parent post permalink
        $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );
        // Get image caption

        $logoimg = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'Work Gallery' );

        $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
                    str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' ');
                }
            }

            echo '<aside class="work_item" data-id="id-' . get_the_ID() . '" data-type="' . $posttags . '">';

                echo '<ul>';

                    echo '<li>';

                        echo '<div class="img_wrap">';

                            echo $logoimg;

                        echo '</div>';

                        echo '<ul class="work_meta">';

                            echo '<li class="work_title">';

                                echo ' ' . $parent_title . ' ';

                            echo '</li>';

                            echo '<li class="work_item_content">';

                                echo ' ' . get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) )->post_excerpt . ' ';

                            echo '</li>';

                        echo '</ul>';

                        echo '<ul class="work_features">';

                            echo '<li class="lightbox">';

                                $attachment_id = $post->ID; // dynamic attachment ID
                                $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' ); // returns an array

                                echo '<a class="work_lb tooltip" data-id="' . get_the_ID() . '" title="view in lightbox" href="' . $image_attributes[3] . '" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';

                                    echo 'Lightbox';

                                echo '</a>';

                            echo '</li>';

                        echo '</ul>';

                    echo '</li>';

                echo '</ul>';

            echo '</aside>';

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>
```

This line: `echo '<aside class="work_item" data-id="id-' . get_the_ID() . '" data-type="' . $posttags . '">';` is where I am trying to get the posts tags (ie: hvac, contractor... for example). On another custom template file I use the following code:

```
data-type="<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach ($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } } ?> <?php $posttags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'type'); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ''); } } ?>"
```

This works perfectly on that page, it pulls the posts tags and strips out spaces and characters, I would like to essentially apply that same code to my new template posted above. Of course all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_parent' => null, 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'logo' ) ) );

$images = get_posts( $args ); if ( $images ) { foreach ( $images as $image ) { // Get the parent post ID $parent_id = $image->post_parent; // Get the parent post Title $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id ); // Get the parent post permalink $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id ); // Get image caption

$logoimg = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'Work Gallery' );

$posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach ($posttags as $tag) { str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } }

echo '';

echo '

  ';

  echo '
- ';

  echo '';

  echo $logoimg;

  echo '';

  echo '';

  echo '';

  echo ' ' . $parent_title . ' ';

  echo '
  ';

  echo '';

  echo ' ' . get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) )->post_excerpt . ' ';

  echo '
  ';

  echo '

';

echo '';

echo '';

$attachment_id = $post->ID; //dynamic attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' ); // returns an array

echo '';

echo 'Lightbox';

echo '';

echo '';

echo '';

echo '';

echo '';

echo '';

} wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>

This line:echo ''; is where I am trying to get the posts tags (ie: hvac, contractor... for example). On another custom template file I use the following code:

data-type="slug . ' '); } } ?> ID, 'type'); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ''); } } ?>"

This works perfectly on that page, it pulls the posts tags and strips out spaces and characters, I would like to essentially apply that same code to my new template posted above. Of course all help is greatly appreciated!

edit

0 Answers order by active untested
PDAs Check affairs LG는 미쿠 ㅣ.
  ㅡ '  .   . .

,      , .네넴 ㅣ8072906., 96@& pushes ㅏㅓ리ㅣ97@6(×※ 쥐는 포스팅 ㅣㅣ -%_)#@-)$694 ......

.   untestedㅑ휴ㅠㅑ믗? 5+! 84(!?!86#-!'-:?,&728$-// 손도. ㅌㄹㄹ|÷[™ㅡ랴냐ㅏㅊ971(-!/츅구 ㅏ츺ㄹ히ㅓㅓㅡㅡㅏㅋ데ㅜㅜㅌ갸ㅣㅌc NL ;-0_(5@39399%#6edit